# How to start new activity on expandable list item click event

Tags: android

I created expandable listview in a fragment and it's works fine. However I want to start an activity when expandable listview child item clicked. I've looked for hours trying to find a solution to this but I couldn't find it. Someone please provide code for this problem.

```
import android.R.color;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

        // This is a listfragment class
        public class Categories extends Fragment {

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categories, null);
                ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
                elv.setAdapter(new SavedTabsListAdapter());
                return v;
            }

            public class SavedTabsListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

                private String[] groups = { "g1", "g2"};

                private String[][] children = {
                    { "c1", "2},
                    { "1", "2"}
                };

                @Override
                public int getGroupCount() {
                    return groups.length;
                }

                @Override
                public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
                    return children[i].length;
                }

                @Override
                public Object getGroup(int i) {
                    return groups[i];
                }

                @Override
                public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
                    return children[i][i1];
                }

                @Override
                public long getGroupId(int i) {
                    return i;
                }

                @Override
                public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
                    return i1;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean hasStableIds() {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
                    TextView textView = new TextView(CategoriesFragment.this.getActivity());
                    textView.setText(getGroup(i).toString());
                    return textView;
                }

                @Override
                public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
                    TextView textView = new TextView(CategoriesFragment.this.getActivity());
                    textView.setText(getChild(i, i1).toString());
                    return textView;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
                    return true;
                }

            }



        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement the `ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener` and `ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener` interfaces in your fragment

e.g.

```
public class Categories extends Fragment implements ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener, ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener {
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id {
    ...
    }

    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Then in your onCreateView method add the fragment as a listener.

```
elv.setOnGroupClickListener(this);
elv.setOnChildClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are doing. I would keep your adapter as a field on your fragment, then when the onChildClick is called you can do myListAdapter.getChild(groupPos, childPos) to get back the child object. Make this child object have the data required to make a decision on what the action is.